# Nesting a TypeScript React component inside another

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I'm trying to nest a TypeScript React component within another, but it complains about types. It would seem it wants me to add all of my props into the parent interface?

Is there a way of doing this without having to have all my types listed in the child component interface, but then also having to add the types to the parent component interface?

**Note:** I am using Styled Components in the example below

```
interface IField {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export function Field({ children, htmlFor, label, required, ...props }: IField) {
  return (
    <FormField {...props}>
      <Label htmlFor={htmlFor} label={label} required={required}/>
      {children}
    </FormField>
  )
}

interface ILabel {
  htmlFor: string
  label: string
  required?: boolean
}

export function Label({ htmlFor, label, required }: ILabel) {
  return (
    <FormLabel htmlFor={htmlFor}>
      {label}
      {required && (
        <Required />
      )}
    </FormLabel>
  )
}
```

Error I get:

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ILabel': htmlFor, label
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Is it complaining on the `Field`'s return? It looks like you're not passing in a required parameter `htmlFor` and you're also not passing in required correctly: `props.required` vs `required` -- as you're not destructuring that key directly.

Comment: Oops, I just fixed the `required ` prop. It's complaining on the `Label` component inside of the `FormField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid adding the properties from the child interface back to the parent component interface you can use `extends` (see [TypeScript inheritance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#inheritance) documentation).

After that, you can pass the `props` from the parent to the child component by using `{...props}` deconstructor on the child component.

And finally, if you are using TypeScript might as well use `React.FunctionComponent` typing to avoid having to manually type `children`.

> You can check at this simplified working example:
>   https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-stackoverflow-60228406

I tried to adapt your snippet below...

```js
import React from 'react';

interface IField extends ILabel {
}

export const Field: React.FunctionComponent<IField> = (props) => {
  return (
    <FormField>
      <Label {...props} />
      {props.children}
    </FormField>
  )
};

interface ILabel {
  htmlFor: string
  label: string
  required?: boolean
}

export const Label: React.FunctionComponent<ILabel> = (props) => {
  return (
    <FormLabel htmlFor={props.htmlFor}>
      {props.label}
      {props.required && (<Required />)}
    </FormLabel>
  )
};
```

Comment: This makes things a lot more clear now, a very concise answer indeed! :) I do have a question however, any particular reason you just use `props` instead of destructuring them like I had already done in my above example?

Comment: Glad it helped you, don't forget to accept the answer ;) Regarding the deconstruction of `props` it's really a matter of preference I guess, I chose to use `props.myProperty` because I find it easier to maintain so that if I add any new prop I don't have to add it to the deconstructed `props` but that's me, it will end up working both ways.

Comment: I thought it could be a matter of preference but just wanted to check :) One last question, if I wanted to extend multiple interfaces, is it as simple as just comma separating them? Example: `interface IField extends ILabel, ISomeInterface {}`

Comment: Yup you got it!

Comment: Awesome stuff! I've made a follow up question here if you'd like to take a crack at it, I really enjoy your explanation of things -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60241936/react-ts-how-to-pass-props-from-a-parent-component-to-a-deeply-nested-child/60242254#60242254