# React TS - How to pass props from a parent component to a deeply nested child

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Currently, I have created some different form elements. I'm trying to create them in a diverse way so I can piece them together to create different formats for a form.

Here are a few of my form elements:

```
// Field Component
interface IField extends ILabel {}

export const Field: React.FunctionComponent<IField> = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Label {...props} />
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

// Label Component
interface ILabel {
  htmlFor: string;
  label: string;
  required?: boolean;
}

export const Label: React.FunctionComponent<ILabel> = props => {
  return (
    <label htmlFor={props.htmlFor}>
      {props.label}
      // Some required icon would go where I've added the <span />.
      {props.required && <span />}
    </label>
  );
};

// Input Wrapper Component
export const InputWrapper: React.FunctionComponent = props => {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};

// Input Component
interface IInput {
  type: string;
  id: string;
  name: string;
  value?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  required?: boolean;
}

export const Input: React.FunctionComponent<IInput> = props => {
  return (
    <input
      type={props.type}
      id={props.id}
      name={props.name}
      value={props.value}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      required={props.required}
    />
  );
};
```

And here's how I implement the component:

```
<Field htmlFor="name" label="Name:" required>
  <InputWrapper>
    <Input
      id="name"
      type="text"
      name="name"
      placeholder="Enter your name..."
    />
  </InputWrapper>
</Field>
```

I would like to be able to set the `required` prop on the `Field` component and it will also get passed down to my `Input` component, no matter how deeply nested it becomes. How is this possible?

I'm also providing a **[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-thunder-2l12h)** demo.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You could use `context` for this - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html.

Comment: Would you mind forking my CodeSandBox to show an example of how you would implement this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `props.children` and that it is impossible to know the exact hierarchy of the nested components, or that it may vary for different use-cases, it can be hard to try to pass the `props` from parent to children.

[Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api) provide a way to share data and react on changes, for a tree of components.

> Your codesandbox adapted to the explained solution
>   https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stackoverflow-60241936-fvkdo

In your case, you would need to create a `Context` for your `Field` component to "share" the `required` field and define a default value.

```js
interface IFieldContext {
  required?: boolean;
}

export const FieldContext = React.createContext<IFieldContext>({
  required: false // default value when the prop is not provided
});
```

Then using `FieldContext.Provider` in the `Field` component you can assign the "shared" values for the nested components.

```js
export const Field: React.FunctionComponent<IField> = props => {
  return (
    <FieldContext.Provider value={{ required: props.required }}>
      <Label {...props} />
      {props.children}
    </FieldContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Finally, in the `Input` component, use `FieldContext.Consumer` to access the "shared" values and retrieve the `required` prop assigned on the `Field` component. You will then be able to remove the `required` field from the `IInput` interface since it now comes from the `Context` and not from `props` anymore.

```js
interface IInput {
  type: string;
  id: string;
  name: string;
  value?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
}

export const Input: React.FunctionComponent<IInput> = props => {
  return (
    <FieldContext.Consumer>
      {context => (
        <input
          type={props.type}
          id={props.id}
          name={props.name}
          value={props.value}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          required={context.required} // access context prop
        />
      )}
    </FieldContext.Consumer>
  );
};
```

And "voila", you can use the `required` prop on the `Field` component and it will be applied on your nested `Input` component, no matter how deep the `Input` is nested... fancy stuff

```js
export const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Field htmlFor="name" label="Name:" required>
      <InputWrapper>
        <Input
          id="name"
          type="text"
          name="name"
          placeholder="Enter your name..."
        />
      </InputWrapper>
    </Field>
  );
};
```

Comment: Once again, another great explanation! Very informative and broken down well, thank you! I have noticed that when I inspect the `input` element, the `value` attribute is added but I don't pass a prop for it, any idea why that is?

Comment: Also, does this work for passing `props` up the tree too? For example, if I wanted to set the `required` prop on my `Input` instead of `Field` and pass it up to my `Label` component? I tried, but I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or it's not possible? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stackoverflow-60241936-62t2q

Comment: Thanks, I try my best to be as descriptive as possible so that you understand what is going on. For the first question, the `value` prop is probably there because of `value={props.value}` applied on the `input` element. For your second question, if you want to set `required` on the `Input` component instead of `Field` you would have to set the `Label` component inside the `Input` component and therefore you don't need `Context` because you know exactly that `Label` would be right under the `Input` component: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stackoverflow-60241936-6769p

Comment: The problem with that is you've moved the `InputWrapper` inside of the `Input` component. My vision with having these components separate is to be able to piece different configurations of components together. I've made this illustration so you can visually see what I'm trying to achieve: https://i.gyazo.com/068b33a010a09a6e916687b2a8dccca0.png

Comment: Besides the `required` prop, another configuration might be wanting to set the `maxLength` on the `Input` component(as I'm trying to to do with required) and displaying the component outside of the `InputWrapper`, illustrated here: https://i.gyazo.com/471b896ed2c22dcd86e976f2876076d2.png

Comment: More like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stackoverflow-60241936-no3-ny3q9

Comment: Yeah, like that, but is there a way of doing it without using state?

Comment: No, I was just curious :) Would you be potentially interesting in some freelance work? Feel free to add my Discord: Sky#7208 and we can discuss further!